# Prevent deletion of Windows.old

Tags: windows, windows-11, windows-11-upgrade

I'd like to force Windows to ***not*** delete Windows.old after an upgrade. I've run into some issues with Windows 11, but I have a long-running task (an upload) and can't rollback. I remember doing a command to set the deletion timer to a ridiculous amount of time before, but I can't remember it or find it.

Comment: Rename the folder.

Answer (score 0):

> I remember doing a command to set the deletion timer to a ridiculous amount of time before, but can't remember it or find it.

The command was as follows so run it as an Administrator:

```
DISM /Online /Set-OSUninstallWindow /Value:60
```

The maximum value is 60 days.  You can query the current Uninstall Window time period by running the following command as an Administrator:

```
DISM /Online /Get-OSUninstallWindow
```

Source: [DISM operating system uninstall command-line options](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-uninstallos-command-line-options?view=windows-11)

Comment: Renaming the folder will prevent the contents of Windows.old from being deleted, if you want to retaining that data, move it out of that folder.  If you rename the folder, and your outside of the uninstall Window, you won’t be able to rollback.